# Problems to tag equations

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm trying to tag my equations, but I'm having the following problem:

When I write the environment "equation" with the command label:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\omega_1\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_1\omega_g$$ 
$$\omega_{r_1}\omega_{s_1},\ldots,
\omega_{r_{g-2}}\omega_{s_{g-2}}$$ 
$$\omega_2\omega_g,\ldots,\omega_g\omega_g
\end{equation}
```

I have (4.1) displayed in the pdf, instead of (1), why? The worse is when I try to use the command $\ref$, what appears in the PDF is just the number 1, instead of 4.1.

Anyone could help me?

Thanks

**EDIT**

My preamble:

```
\documentclass[‎fleqn,a4paper,12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs, amsfonts, amsmath}
\usepackage{amsbsy, hyperref}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage[labelfont=rm,format=plain,indention=0cm,singlelinecheck=off,justification=raggedright,skip=2pt]{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{parskip} 
\usepackage{setspace}


 \geometry{
a4paper,total={210mm,297mm},
 left=30mm,right=20mm,
 top=30mm,bottom=20mm,
 } 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\Alph{paragraph}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {0.0001pt \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {0.0001pt \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize}}
\counterwithin{paragraph}{subsubsection}
\counterwithin{subparagraph}{paragraph}

\counterwithin*{paragraph}{section}                     
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}                                                
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{2cm}


\setlength\parskip{0cm} 

\setcounter{page}{0} 

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\normalsize{\csname the#1\endcsname}
\hspace{0.1em}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\l@section            {\bf \@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{4em}}
\renewcommand\l@subsection      {\bf \@dottedtocline{2}{0em}{4em}}
\renewcommand\l@subsubsection{\bf \@dottedtocline{3}{0em}{4em}}
\renewcommand\l@paragraph{\rm \@dottedtocline{4}{0em}{4.5em}}
\renewcommand\l@subparagraph{\rm \@dottedtocline{5}{0em}{4.5em}}


\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\contentsname{\center \normalsize{SUM\'ARIO}}}

\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\listtablename{\center \normalsize{LISTA DE TABELAS}}
}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Tabela }
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{ -- }
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{4.6em}



\newlistof{grafico}{graf}{\center \normalsize{\bf LISTA DE GR\'AFICOS}}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Gr\'afico},fileext=graf]{grafico}

\setlength{\cftgraficoindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\cftgraficopresnum}{Gr\'afico }
\renewcommand{\cftgraficoaftersnum}{ -- }
\setlength{\cftgraficonumwidth}{4.8em}


\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0em}

\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{ -- }
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{4.6em}

\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=30mm,bmargin=20mm,lmargin=30mm,rmargin=20mm}


\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Observaçao}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corolário}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Exemplo}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definição}[section]
\renewcommand{\proofname}{Prova}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lema}[section]

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposição}[section]

\newcommand{\bigslant}[2]{{\raisebox{.9em}{$#1$}\left/\raisebox{-.9em}{$#2$}\right.}}
\newcommand{\lt}{<}
\newcommand{\gt}{>}


\newenvironment{quoting}
   \small\singlespacing
   \begin{list}{}{%
       \setlength{\listparindent}{0cm}%
       \setlength{\itemindent}{\listparindent}%
       \setlength{\rightmargin}{0cm}%
       \setlength{\leftmargin}{4cm}%
       \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}%
    \item\relax}%
  {\end{list}}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

Comment: What is your preamble?

Comment: Please edit the question to contain  a _complete_ small document so that people can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've changed to \align* with the label command and this made the tag disappeared :(

Comment: @Bernard see my edit please

Comment: sorry the edit is not useful: you have added dozens of lines unrelated to the original equation, but the result is still not a complete document that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the culprit may be `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`?

If you leave that away, what do you get?

Comment: you're right! thank you, this preamble wasn't made by me, that's why I didn't identify the error.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reset equation numbers at each new section, but don't want the section number to be displayed, use

```
\numberwithin*{equation}{section}
```

(with a star).